# How to create timer in Android Studio ( kotlin )?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, timer

i wanted to create a program in Android Studio, using kotlin, where i use timer which does an action every ~20 milliseconds and runs infinitely. I used something like this:

```kotlin
object : CountDownTimer(10000,20){
   override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

   }
   override fun onFinish() {
      start()
   }
}.start()
```

But the problem is, after some time, the timer starts slowing down, and when 1 sec should pass, it actually is 6 seconds. Changing the actions to 40 milliseconds or more only helps for a little while, because later it still slows down. I saw that people used timer that actually works like this without any problem, but it was in Java, and when i tried to change it into Kotlin with Android Studio's help (i never used Java), it ended up not working (after launching, the app crashed everytime). Does someone know how to create or use different timer other than CountDownTimer that i showed above which is in kotlin?

**Edit:
I forgot to add the code that works for me. It's basically the one i accepted as answer but i had to make some changes to make it work, so here it is:**

```kotlin
val timerName = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   while (isActive) {
      lifecycleScope.launch {
        doSomething()
      }
   delay(20L)
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @cutiko i want to make a game, where points are added every specific time.

Comment: If you're writing in Kotlin, you can just `launch` a coroutine which just delays 20ms in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most probably happens because the function in `onTick()` and `onFinish()` are invoked within the same coroutine that the counter works, so probably you would need to `launch` another coroutine there to not block the timer scope

Also this `CountDownTimer` API is experimental at this moment so I guess it is not really recomended to use it, probably you could do something like this:

```
val timerJob = scope.launch(Dispatcher.IO) {
   while (isActive) {
       scope.launch { doSomething() }
       delay(20L)
   }
}
```

I didn't test it but it should have exactly same behavior (but not blocking the timer), it will run until the `scope` will cancel itself (f.e. lifecycle scopes) or you will cancel it manually by calling `timerJob.cancel()`

The `isActive` boolean takes care of checking if coroutine is still active (so the loop won't "leak")

Unfortunately if you run some heavy stuff in this `doSomething()` call that will exceed this 20 milisec delay there will happen some concurrency issues so it should be simple

If your "game" is so heavy that this 20 milisec delay will be too small then most probably using coroutines is not the best approach for your idea

Comment: Okay, so i tested this, and it works perfectly ( btw, you forgot "s" at the end of "Dispatcher" ) but i wanted to ask, is there a way to pause it and resume when i want it to ?

Comment: Nope, but you can always call `timerJob.cancel()` to pause it and if you want to resume it you can just recreate this job if you know what I mean

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not sure how to recreate it ( if you don't mean, writing the same code again )

Comment: Let's say that this block of code is a function, `timerJob` is a class scoped variable, then you will have f.e. `start()` function that will run the code sample I've written above (assigning the class scoped variable `timerJob`), and then there would be a function `pause()` that with use of the reference to this `timerJob` will call `timerJob.cancel()`, then if you want to resume this timer you just recreate the timer with use of `start()` function like at the beginning